# Failed to create a new virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox

I am really new in Linux  and I want to set up a VirtualBox VM with windows.
My problem is that it returns this message when I create it:

```
Failed to create a new virtual machine.
Machine settings file '/home/george/VirtualBox VMs/George/George.vbox' already exists
```

Answer (score 8):

You should create another Virtuabox Image with another name or delete that file George.vbox

Answer (score 1):

You should delete George.box and try `vagrant up`

Answer (score 0):

You can double click on `George.vbox` icon and virtual box will make things up for you.

I had the same situation, I was trying to add same VM image after deleting existing one - the same one that I wanted to reset. After 10 or more tries, I just double clicked on on icon in folder instead of adding it via `Import` interface in `VirtualBox` and I got my machine as I wanted it.